# Using highlight_max and highlight_min from pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I want to highlight the maximum value in each row as green and the minimum value as red.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
value = np.random.normal(size=(5,5)) #Generate random data

df = pd.DataFrame(value)
display(df.style.highlight_max(color = 'lightgreen', axis = 1)) # This works for max part
display(df.style.highlight_min(color = 'red', axis = 1)) # This also works for min part
```

But combining those 2 code like this :

```
df.style.highlight_min(color = 'red', axis = 1).style.highlight_max(color = 'lightgreen', axis = 1)
```

give me this error

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'
```

What is the correct way to use both of them? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And it turns out that I don't need to call another style attribute. Will leave this for future readers who have the same problem with me :)

```
df.style.highlight_min(color = 'red', axis = 1).highlight_max(color = 'lightgreen', axis = 1)
```

will work.